# Reading in values from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a file that looks somewhat like this:

```c
6 3
0 4 5 5 6 9
1 11 21 2 22 23
```

I want to read in the first 2 numbers and store them into two separate ints, namely n and m respectively. The second line I want to read into a dynamically allocated int array of size 2*m and the third line I want to read into a dynamically allocated int array of size n. I have another function (that is void) that will take these arrays and generate a dynamically allocated int array of size m. I then want to write the contents of that array into an output file. How would I go about doing that?

I've tried using `fscanf(input_ptr, "%d", &n)` and `fscanf(input_ptr, "%d\n", &m)` to read the first two numbers but I'm not sure if the %d\n is the correct way to go to the next line. I'm not sure how I would go about reading in the next two lines for the two arrays they correspond to.

Comment: Post the code you tried, not only 1 line of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the first 2 numbers with a single call to `fscanf()`:

```
int n, m;
if (fscanf(input_ptr, "%d%d", &n, &m) != 2) {
   /* invalid input */
   return 1;
}
```

Adding a trailing `\n` in the format string is useless and has side effects: `fscanf()` will keep reading from `input_ptr` until it gets a byte that is not white space, preventing the newline from acting as an input terminator.

For the following input, allocate the arrays and read the numbers in 2 loops with `fscanf(input_ptr, "%d", &x)`, always checking the return value for successful input.